# Syntax error (missing operator) in query expression '* b_forte ORDER BY ProdDate DESC' error message

Tags: sql, database, vb.net, ms-access-2010

In my program I am connecting to a Access 2010 database, from there I am using a SQL statement to read the top 30 records in that query. The problem I have when I am reading is that I get the error message: **"Syntax error (missing operator) in query expression '* b_forte ORDER BY ProdDate DESC'"**. I am not 100% sure what I am missing inside my statement, and I could not find a solution online. The code that I am using is as follows:

```
    Public Sub CheckForRepeat()

    Dim mydb As String
    Dim mystr As String

    Dim connection As OleDb.OleDbConnection
    'Connection string to connect to database.
    mystr = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=C:\Forte\Fortedb.accdb"
    connection = New OleDb.OleDbConnection(mystr)

    'Opening database.
    connection.Open()

    'Select top 30 records from database organizing by the date, and line ID.
    mydb = "SELECT TOP 30 * b_forte ORDER BY ProdDate DESC, BaleLine DESC"

    'Will display the SQL statement if DisplayCode is checked off.
    If GlobalVariables.DisplayCode = True Then
        MainTextBox.AppendText(Environment.NewLine & mydb)
    End If

    Dim run = New OleDb.OleDbCommand

    run = New OleDbCommand(mydb, connection)
    'Executing the SQL statement.
    run.ExecuteNonQuery()
    connection.Close()

End Sub
```

The error message is firing at `run.ExecuteNonQuery()`, I think that I must be missing something inside my SQL statement.`b_forte`, `ProdDate`, and `BaleLine` are all valid inside my Access 2010 database, and the connection string is correct, as I use it earlier in my code to connect to the same database.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use the `FROM` keyword.

```
SELECT TOP 30 * FROM b_forte ORDER BY ProdDate DESC, BaleLine DESC
```

Comment: Hahahahah well, thank you for making me feel dumb. But even more; thank you for hleping hahahahhah. Can't believe I missed that.

Answer (score 2):

You are not including the table name in your query (and therefore no FROM clause)...

Your query should look like this :

```
SELECT TOP 30 b_forte FROM TableName ORDER BY ProdDate DESC, BaleLine DESC
```

Comment: the table name was b_forte. So as Darren had stated, I needed the `FROM` infont of the TableName.

Comment: Alright! b_forte is a weird table name that's why I tought it was a column ;-)

Comment: hahah yeah, it's my boss' name he came up with. Made the same mistake earlier today.

Comment: I clearly get that, our boss came up with multiple weird names too :-P